# 'ethers' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/scrappy-squirrels/tutorial-building-a-web3-frontend-with-react-e0a87ea3bad), and I'm trying to make a React app. I think that I'm using updated versions of React.js, Ethers, and Webpack. I've followed the instructions and up to this point everything has been going fine. However when it comes to Ethers, I get the following error:

> 'ethers' is not defined  no-undef

Here is my `app.js`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import './App.css';
import contract from './Contracts/NFTCollectible.json';
const contractAddress = "0x0024786Eb4E2FF93b17C22EddeA2573F883FEb8d";
const abi = contract.abi;

function App() {
const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState(null);


  const checkWalletIsConnected = async () => {
const { ethereum } = window;


if(!ethereum){
    console.log("Clearly, a wallet is needed.")
    return;
}
else{
    console.log("Yay! You're all set up!")
}

const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts'});

if(accounts.length !== 0){
    const account = accounts[0];
    console.log("Found an authroized account:", account);
    setCurrentAccount(account); 
}else{
    console.log("No authorised account found!");
}
      }

  const connectWalletHandler = async () => { 
  const { ethereum } = window;
  
  if(!ethereum)
  {
      alert("Please install Metamsk!");
  }
  try {
      
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
      console.log("Found an account! Address: ", accounts[0]);
      setCurrentAccount(accounts[0]);
     } catch(err){
         console.log(err)
     }
  
  }

  const mintNftHandler = async () => { 
  try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      
      if (ethereum){
          const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
          const signer = provider.getSigner();
          const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
          
          console.log("Initialize payment!");
          let nftTxn = await nftContract.mintNFTs(1, { value: ethers.parseEther("0.01") });
          
          console.log("Mining... please wait!");
          await nftTxn.wait();
          
          console.log(`Mined, see transaction https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/${nftTxn.hash}`);
          
      }else{
          console.log("Ethereum object doesn't exist.");
      }
     
      

      
  }
  catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }

  
  }

  const connectWalletButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={connectWalletHandler} className='cta-button connect-wallet-button'>
        Connect Wallet (No scam)
      </button>
    )
  }

  const mintNftButton = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={mintNftHandler} className='cta-button mint-nft-button'>
        Mint NFT (Again, no scam)
      </button>
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWalletIsConnected();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='main-app'>
      <h1>Bored Bits</h1>
      <div>
        {currentAccount ? mintNftButton() : connectWalletButton()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nft-collectible-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "ethers": "^6.1.0",
    "hardhat-ethers": "^1.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^5.76.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried removing all of my modules, and then re-importing everything, but that didn't help. I've seen other posts like this, and for them the solution is: either `const ethers = require("ethers")` or `const { ethers } = require("hardhat");`, but for me this brings up hundreds of other errors, the first one being: `process is not defined` and the rest of them following the pattern of: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve XXX in example/path`. Also, I have both `ethers` and `hardhat-ethers` installed.

Answer (score 1):

This line here:

`const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);`

You have ethers V6 on your project and the entry providers doesn't exist. You need to use:

`ethers.JsonRpcProvider(ethereum)`

Also there is no `parseEther`. You need to do the math yourself, like:

`const formatedAmount = Number(amount) / Number(10 ** 18)`